# Head First Java Swing example code gives different behavior on Ubuntu and MacOS

Tags: java, swing

Same snippet of Java code gives different result on Ubuntu 18.04 and MacOS X.

Hi, I'm reading the book Head First Java, english version. In Chapter 12 about Swing, there is an example called SimpleAnimation on page 385. In the original code, the program is supposed to draw a track of the movement of a circle. I have achieved this result using a Ubuntu 18.04 machine with Java 8(Didn't remember the specific version). However, on a MacOS X machine with Java 8.0_201, the program automatically clears the track of the circle movement. Does anyone know why this happened?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class SimpleAnimation {

    int x = 70;
    int y = 70;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleAnimation gui = new SimpleAnimation();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 130; i++) {
            x++;
            y++;
            //System.out.println("VALUE OF X AND Y : " +x +" " +y);
            drawPanel.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

    }// close go() method


    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);

        }
    } // close inner class
} // close outer class
```

Expected: The animation shows the movement track of the circle. (Achieved on Ubuntu 18.04)
Actual: The track is erased automatically. (Appeared on MacOS X)

Comment: Probably not the root of your problem but Swing is not thread safe.  GUI components should be initialized on the Event Dispatch Thread. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: Your paintComponent method *should* call the `super.paintComponent(g);` parent method as its first call. If you want to store image data, then draw to a BufferedImage or create an `ArrayList<Point>` and draw from that.

Comment: So basically *Head First Java* is broken?  I did a quick read through of that book and I didn't like it, but I never tested any examples.  Personally I prefer the O'Reily book *Learning Java.* @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Further to the advice of @HovercraftFullOfEels. the effect of **not** calling the super method is indeterminate. The JRE might repaint the entire component (causing the past paints to be erased by the BG color of the component) .. or not. Either behavior is valid.

Comment: @markspace Maybe *Head First Java* should have been *Off With His Head First Java*. But maybe that title was not considered as catchy, or did not appeal to the author's sense of humor.